# Is there a good tool for monitoring network activity on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, networking, bandwidth

Is there a good bit of software on Mac OS X that I can use to monitor incoming and outgoing network activity? Nothing too geeky, I just want something simple to use.

I'm on version 10.6 (Snow Leopard) if that helps.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is widely acknowledged as one of the best network monitor tools available. Distributions are available for [OS X](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html).

If you prefer something more simplistic you can use [iStatMenus](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) to show incoming / outgoing network traffic speeds.

For the person who doesn't want to install anything you can also use [tcpdump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcpdump) in Terminal.

```
tcpdump -i [interface, en0 is ethernet, en1 is wireless]
```

Comment: iStatMenus looks like the day to day winner, but I also appreciate the terminal command too for the quick/dirty way of doing it.

Comment: Wireshark is a packet analyzer with delusions of grander. It doesn't give a good view of everything going on, but it's great for going through packets with a hex editor.

Comment: tcpdump is what I need here - for some reason, Private Eye wasn't showing me FTPS passive connections, but tcpdump did.

Answer (score 52):

Also check out [nettop](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/nettop.1.html), a little command line gem that ships with Mac OS.

Comment: There is a useful 'delta output' mode which can be toggled with the 'd' key while app is running. It will show you the actual download/upload rates per second per connection.

Comment: Pressing the 'd' key didn't do anything for me (macOS 10.12.3) until I first ran nettop -d. It may have been that my terminal window wasn't wide enough initially. Pressing 'h' while running displays other available options.

Comment: `nettop -t wifi -P` has proven a good default for me.

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: I like `nettop -t external -l0 -P -d -s3` to see which processes are currently sending/receiving over the network. You can see what the options mean via `nettop -h`, of course.

Answer (score 31):

Also look at [MenuMeters](http://www.ragingmenace.com/software/menumeters/). I tried iStat Menus & MenuMeters and preferred MM.  Not saying one is better; just that there are a couple of choices.

A working version of [MenuMeters](http://www.ragingmenace.com/software/menumeters/) for El Capitan can be found [here](http://member.ipmu.jp/yuji.tachikawa/MenuMetersElCapitan/).

[image]

Comment: +1. MenuMeters beats iStat Menus anyday.

Comment: MM is also open-source.

Comment: Light, functional and open-source application. What more can we ask? :)

Comment: Unfortunately this no longer works as of osx 10.11.1 El Capitan.

Comment: I can confirm that the version of MenuMeters for El Capitan at http://member.ipmu.jp/yuji.tachikawa/MenuMetersElCapitan/ works as expected on that O/S.

Comment: Still fully functional in Sierra 12.6.

Comment: Try `brew cask install menumeters` if you use brew package manager

Comment: Still working in Mojave 10.14.6

Comment: Thanks for your sharing! This is exactly what I am looking for a long time!

Answer (score 15):

[LittleSnitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html)! - 30$

It is mainly a software Firewall that may help you to prevent some apps to access the internet. It also has a nice menubar icon with live network usage. Mouseover on it and it displays which app is communicating with which server or ip address.

I have LittleSnitch and [iStat Menus](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) installed. Both are complementary.

Comment: LittleSnitch will be a pain unless you're explicitly blocking stolen / cracked programs from calling home. Also the menu item is not nearly as informative as iStat. You'd have to open up the Network Monitor screen to get any benefit.

Comment: Well, there is a lot of programs that are calling home and should not. If you are a bit concerned about security you will understand what I mean.

The LittleSnitch's mouseouver pop-up is also great for showing realtime process-host network activity. But yes, it is not as informative as iStat. That's why i use both.

Comment: little snitch currently shows me my network history graph for one hour. is MenuMeters and Istat show less. do we have anything that shows more than 1 hour, say one day or a week?

Answer (score 7):

Commercial (16$) [iStat Pro](http://www.islayer.com/apps/istatpro/) and [iStat Menus](http://www.islayer.com/apps/istatmenus/) (dashboard widget and menu bar item respectively) are great for monitoring everything from network activity to CPU temperatures.

And of course there's the network tab of Activity Monitor.

Comment: +1 For mentioning Activity Monitor. For anyone with casual requirements who just needs to know their up/down speed this is a great solution, and it ships free with OS X.

Comment: iStat Pro no longer appears to be supported.

Answer (score 2):

Network Logger for Mac OS X from Group Mind does a great job of tracking network traffic, downtime (in real time, with timed log), and lots of easy-to-understand stuff.  I'm not technical and all I really wanted was to track when my ISP connection went down, and for how long it stayed down.  Mac's little Network Utility app would ping endlessly but wouldn't give me a chronological log.  Network Logger did, and was easy for a novice to understand.

Cost me $5.99 from the App Store.

Comment: Good first post. To round out your answer perhaps you could include a link to the app and a screenshot? Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

/System/Library/CoreServices/Network Diagnostics 
Simple green/red LEDs for various layers.  I slide it over to the right side of the screen until just the lights show.

Comment: Tempted to downvote...  How does this help "monitor incoming and outgoing network activity"?  (If it does, please let me know; I'd love to use it!)

Comment: I don't think this does what you think it does. This tool (command is `/System/Library/CoreServices/Network\ Diagnostics.app/Contents/MacOS/Network\ Diagnostics`) diagnosis WiFi or Ethernet connection issues. It doesn't monitor network activity.

Answer (score 0):

I've just installed [Net Monitor and Net Monitor Sidekick](http://homepage.mac.com/rominar/net.html) and so far I like them.  Nothing you can't get with other tools, but a nice summary display.  Each is $10 after a 30 day eval, so YMMV, but I thought I'd mention them.

Comment: The URL provided is dead. The URL for Net Monitor and Net Monitor Sidekick has been updated to http://netmonitor.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/