# What's a good, light, unintrusive and free tool to monitor network/internet speed for the Mac?

Tags: mac, internet, speed, network-monitoring

I need to know how much internet activity is taking place on my iMac. I don't want something very detailed like [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) or some professional network analysis tool. I'm looking at something simple that can simply upload/download speeds in the Mac OS Menu Bar next to the WiFi and other icons.

If you've used [DUMeter](http://www.hageltech.com/dumeter/about) or [NetMeter](http://www.metal-machine.de/readerror/) on Windows, you know what I'm talking about.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/123001/is-there-a-good-tool-for-monitoring-network-activity-on-mac-os-x mentions iStat - have you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer from another question. [iStat Menus](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) and [MenuMeters](http://www.ragingmenace.com/software/menumeters/) do what I need.

Thanks to @Sathya!

Comment: The proper way to handle this is to request that the user leave the comment as an answer. He deserves the rep.

Comment: iStat Menus is not free and MenuMeters is not compatible with elCrapitan